# ASP.NET Expression is not a method

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting a build error, "Expression is not a method" for the following code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
          'LOOKUP SKU DATA ON BLUR
          Dim lookup As String = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(txtSKU, "", False)
          txtSKU.Attributes.Add("onblur", "doLookup()")

          If Not IsPostBack Then
               If txtSKU.Text <> "" Then
                    lookup() '*************the error points to this line*******
               End If
          End If

     End Sub

     Protected Sub btnLookup_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) Handles btnLookup.Command
          lookup()
     End Sub

     Protected Sub lookup()
          'BLAH BLAH BLAH
     End Sub
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've declared a local variable with the same name in the method:

```
Dim lookup As String = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(txtSKU, "", False)
```

In short, don't do that :) Simply rename the variable and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have caught that myself!  Better make another cup of coffee!

Answer (score 1):

you have declared lookup string within the same method and also lookup function.

Change name of your string and it will work.